# Stack Apps register page: "Enable Client Side OAuth Flow" position

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

On the registration [page for registering API applications](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)

[image]

Shouldn't the **Enable Client Side OAuth Flow** checkbox appear beneath the **Application Icon** field?

Comment: Maybe, but it definitely should not stick to the text input border!

Answer (score 2):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) meanwhile:

[image]

but as mentioned [here](https://stackapps.com/q/8397/34061), there's already a new problem with the Edit App form.